# How to remove text followed by a special characted in MSQL

Tags: sql, substring, special-characters, trim, charindex

I have a table named 'country' with a column named 'name'
and the names in this column appears with  translation followed by special character '/'.

```
IRELAND/IRLANDE
GREECE/GRÈCE
DENMARK/DANEMARK
```

Now i want only the countrynames before this special character'/' so the out put should look like this..

```
IRELAND
GREECE
DENMARK
```

please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried this one..SELECT DISTINCT
SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(names)),1,LEN(names)-CHARINDEX('/',names))
FROM [country]         but while this works for some cells doesnt work for all by which i mean i still get 1or2 text followed by this special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 create table #t(name nvarchar(40))
insert into #t values('IRELAND/IRLANDE')
,('GREECE/GRÈCE')
,('DENMARK/DANEMARK')


select substring(name,0,CHARINDEX('/',name)) from #t
```

Answer (score 0):

Why LEN(names)-CHARINDEX('/',names)?
try using CHARINDEX('/',names)+1 instead.

As far as I remember, SUBSTRING's third variables should be the length of the desired output string.

Answer (score 0):

A more complex query to help you out:

```
DECLARE @Text     VARCHAR(50) = 'IRELAND/IRLANDE GREECE/GRÈCE DENMARK/DANEMARK'
    SELECT
 SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@Text,0,CHARINDEX(' ',@Text,0)),0,CHARINDEX('/',@Text,0))
 +  
 SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@Text,CHARINDEX(' ',@Text,0),CHARINDEX(' ',@Text,0)),0,CHARINDEX('/',@Text,0))
 + ' '
 +
 REPLACE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@Text),CHARINDEX('/',@Text,0) + 1 ,CHARINDEX('/',@Text,0))),'/', ' ')
```